# Virtual Method in a Base class to use a Static variable from a child class

Tags: c#, inheritance, static, polymorphism

Is it possible for a Virtual Method in a Base class to reference/access/use a Static variable from a child class?

Its probably easier to explain in code. In the following example is it possible to make the virtual method `Arc::parseFile()` look for `data_arc`?

```
public class Base {
    public static string DATA_3D = "data_3d";

    public virtual void parseFile(string fileContents) {

        // Example of file contents: "data_3d (0,0,0),(1,1,1),(2,2,2)
        // Example of file contents: "data_arc (0,0,0),(1,1,1),(2,2,2)
        // Example of file contents: "data_point (0,0,0)
        string my3dPoints = fileContents.Split(DATA_3D)[1];
    }
}

public class Arc : Base {
    public static string DATA_3D = "data_arc"; 

    // Will the base method parseFile() correctly look for "data_arc" 
    // and NOT data_3d??
}
```

Comment: That is really not such a good idea.  Why not add a virtual getter method and assign the static string value to a data member in the classes constructor?

Comment: @OldProgrammer the reason why I did it is because if it worked it would be a very elegant and simple solution. Only have to change 1 variable value (the static variable) and the parse funtion will work for all types of strings (series of vertices).

Comment: Did you notice a warning about the field in `Arc` hiding the field in `Base`? It is always never a good idea to hide members from the base class. You want a `virtual` get-only property. It cannot be `static`, unfortunately, but the value returned by the `get` accessor can be constant or "static" in any sense.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is it possible for a Virtual Method in a Base class to reference/access/use a Static variable from a child class?

No. Even aside from the static side of things, you're trying to access a variable as if variables were polymorphic. They're not.

The simplest approach would be to make an abstract virtual property, and override it in each method. Then your concrete method in the base class (which may not need to be virtual at all) can call the abstract property.

Alternatively, if you don't mind having a field per instance, just make your base class constructor take a delimiter to split on in the constructor, and store that in a field declared by the base class:

```
public class Base
{
    private readonly string delimiter;

    protected Base(string delimiter)
    {
        this.delimiter = delimiter;
    }

    // Quite possibly no need for this to be virtual at all
    public void ParseFile(string fileContents)
    {
        string my3dPoints = fileContents.Split(delimiter)[1];
    }
}
```

As an aside, I'm not sure I'd use `Split` in this case given you data file - I'd just check whether the line starts with the given prefix.

Comment: +1. I think that question as asked should be answered "yes, base class can use `Arc.DATA_3D` just fine, but it is not what you are looking for".

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov: But the question is actually asking whether calling `parseFile` on an instance of `Arc` would automatically use `Arc.DATA_3D`, in which case the answer is "no" instead.